# How to provide a variable when reading sessionScope in cs javascipt?

Tags: xpages

I want to read the value from a sessionScope in clientside javascript. However I need to calculate the key for which value to collect e.g.:

```
var sessionKey = "type_" + userLocale;
var keyword_type = '#{javascript: sessionScope.get(' + sessionKey + ').get('values')}';
```

I get the error message:

> Error while executing JavaScript computed expression Script
> interpreter error, line=1, col=39: 'sessionScope.get()' is null
>
> 1:  sessionScope.get(' + sessionKey + ').get('values')

Is there any way I can provide a variable when I try to read the sessionScope?

Comment: The final CSJS is determined on the server before being sent to the browser so you can not use this approach to determine the key. Is the key available on the server before hand?

Comment: I am not ashamed to plug the following approach but I would recommend to use a rpc service: <xp:text escape="false">
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var scope = sessionScope.get("type_" + context.getLocaleString()).get('values');
var values = scope.toString();
var out="<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
out += "var keyword_type = '" + values + "';\n";
out += "console.log('hell awaits');\n";
out += "</script>";
out}]]></xp:this.value>
 </xp:text>